# Can not get data with "ThenInclude" - this is not working in C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have 3 entities like this:

```
public class Doctor : BaseEntity
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string About { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Expert> Experts {  get; set; }
    public ICollection<DoctorClinicShifts> DoctorClinicShift { get; set; }
}

public class DoctorClinicShifts : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual Clinic Clinic { get; set; }
    public long ClinicId { get; set; }
    public virtual Shift Shift { get; set; }
    public long ShiftId { get; set; }
    public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
    public long DoctorId { get; set; }
}

public class Clinic : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClinicImage> ClinicImages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DoctorClinicShifts> DoctorClinicShift { get; set; }
}
```

I want data from doctors and clinic, but I can't get that data with this command:

```
var doctors = _context.Doctors
                      .Include(p => p.DoctorClinicShift)
                      .ThenInclude(p => p.Clinic);
```

It doesn't work and I can't get the clinics data.

If you can help me, I will appreciated it very much.

my dbcontext : it has no specific configuration

```
    public class DataBaseContext : DbContext, IDataBaseContext
{
    public DataBaseContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
            
    }

    public DbSet<Clinic> Clinics { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClinicImage> ClinicImages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DoctorClinicShifts> DoctorClinicShift { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Shift> Shifts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Expert> Experts { get; set; }
}
public interface IDataBaseContext
{
    DbSet<Clinic> Clinics { get; set; }
    DbSet<ClinicImage> ClinicImages { get; set; }
    DbSet<DoctorClinicShifts> DoctorClinicShift { get; set; }
    DbSet<Shift> Shifts { get; set; }
    DbSet<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }
    DbSet<Expert> Experts { get; set; }
    int SaveChanges();
    int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);

    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);

    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}
```

the problem is I Cant Get clinic Name or City with code.

Comment: sorry it was a spelling mistake. but with ThenInclude(p => p.Clinic) it doesn't work neither

Comment: Can you share your models configuration? And what version of library you are using? What is BaseEntity class?

Comment: @NaghmeVahabi please show the configuration for your migration, you can update your question

Comment: I checked your model on my db and it seems to be working ok, I removed shifts and clinic images and added a base class with [Key] public long Id { get; set; }. Mine is efcore 7

Comment: Did you show the complete code of the entity classes? You don't happen to initialize navigation properties (for example `Clinic = new Clinic()`? Also, side note: do yourself a favor an use singular names for classes and plural for collection properties.

Comment: @Serhii my dbcontext has no specific configuration. I use efcore 8

Comment: @Mykola Can Your Share how you get to clinic's name or city with code?

Comment: What Mykola  is saying is: I used the code as you show it and it worked. And I agree, seemingly there's nothing wrong with it. There must be something you don't show. You didn't answer my question yet, Another question is: what does the SQL query look like? (The one generated by `_context.Doctors.Include ...`)

Comment: Check the table columns and foreign keys to ensure you don't have any extra shadow properties. Since you haven't defined any navigations explicitly, maybe EF is inventing extra's in ways you didn't expect.

Comment: Are you getting an exception, or just simply getting back a Null Clinic, or empty Doctor.DoctorShiftClinics?  If you are getting back a #null result the first thing I would check is inspect the connection string at runtime with a breakpoint and see that it is going to the same database instance you are checking against:  `var connectionString = _context.Database.GetConnectionString();` That could be pointing at a older test database missing the data you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that navigation properties in your entities marked as **virtual**. This enables lazy loading and helps with eager loading using **Include**
2. Materialize your results, for example using **.ToList()**

   var doctors = _context.Doctors
   .Include(p => p.DoctorClinicShift)
   .ThenInclude(dc => dc.Clinic)
   .ToList();